# Cant ping externally raspberry pi3+

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, ping

New to Raspberry pi so this may be a rookie problem. I installed Raspbian as per instructions and all seems well, including browsing, compilations etc. I am connected via wifi and ifconfig shows a valid ip address for wlan0.

ping 127.0.0.0 gives:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.102 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.119 ms
```

ping google.com gives:

```
PING google.com(syd09s12-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4006:803::200e)) 56 data bytes
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
645 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 669783ms
```

So clearly not working. What am I doing wrong?
Same result for all external addresses - but Chromium working fine.

Here is the config output is that helps:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig -a
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:ec:f0:2c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 32  bytes 2968 (2.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 32  bytes 2968 (2.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.32  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 2001:8003:890f:c000:9a9b:2baa:67db:a48b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::bf92:3e2a:3ede:678  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:b9:a5:79  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3109  bytes 1605135 (1.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3909  bytes 521901 (509.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: try `ping -4 google.com` - see if it's some ipv6 issue (did not realise telstra issued ipv6 yet)

Comment: Yes that worked... I will read up some more on ping -4 and get back if I need more explanation

Comment: Ipv4 vs ipv6 ... seems your ipv6 isn't working

Comment: Ok just enforcing IP4 .... thank you. I have Telstra NBN which by the way has proven to be fast and reliable over pst 2 years (once the torture of applying and actually getting connected is endured).

Comment: @Jaromanda make a reply and I will accept.

Comment: As i said. Surprised ipv6 at all enabled

Comment: It's not really a raspberry pi specific issue though, as it turns out, so, like a couple of answers I've posted recently, it makes no sense if the question is "closed" for being off topic - I think some moderators are heavy handed :p

Comment: Please check your network setup as described in [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/79866).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have already done this, but I always disable IPV6 on the Pi (and everywhere else):

edit 
     /etc/sysctl.conf
add:
     net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1

sudo sysctl -p
or reboot :)